# Заполнение массива в соответствии с условиями

Tags: python, алгоритм, numpy, анализ-данных, искусственный-интеллект

> Есть массив x*y (строка, столбец)
>
> Данный массив заполняется циклом отдельно по одной ячейке в строке значениями 1 или 0.
> Условия:
>
> 1. Значения заполняются рандомно, но в итоге все должно заполниться 1.
> 2. Если по х (в строке) все 0, берется первое значение. Если уже были попытки заполнения, то берется ячейка, с самой первой попыткой заполнения.
> 3. Переход к заполнению ячеек в новой строке происходит, только если в
>    предыдущей строке есть не менее 2-х ячеек со значением 1.
> 4. Ячейки новой строки заполняются только для ячеек, у которых в
>    предыдущей строке стоит 1, и это не может быть столбец, куда
>    вносилась 1 предыдущей итерации.

Подскажите какой использовать алгоритм, или к каким алгоритмам присмотреться. Просто не хватает немного знаний в этой области.
Реализация будет на python3

Comment: 2 и 4 пункты непонятны

Comment: Их скорее всего можно объеденить. Очередная итерация переходит к заполнению ячейки новой строки. Ячейка берется только та, у которой в предыдущей строке стоит 1. Предположим в этой строке есть несколько таких ячеек, и из них нужно выбрать ту, которая в предыдущей строке, раньше всех получила 1.

Comment: `берется первое значение` - что есть первое значение?  `Если уже были попытки заполнения` -  ??? Пример не помешает.

Comment: Алгоритм вы уже написали. Вроде как вы его понимаете. Действуйте по нему и всё.

Comment: "ничего не понял, но очень интересно". приведите пример алгоритма решения "на пальцах".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе задача решается если к заполняемым данным добавить временные метки, например: (1, 29.09.2022_12:20)

Действие алгоритма на примере: есть матрица 3*3, все значения none

```
none,none,none
none,none,none
none,none,none
```

Запускаем цикл. Каждая итерация цикла должна проходить по новой строке, но у нас условие, переход на новую строку, как только в строке появятся две единицы, иначе мы проходим по всем none, а потом и по всем 0, пока не будет выполнено наше условие, получаем

```
1, 0, 1
none,none,none
none,none,none
```

Теперь проходим ко второй строчке, но только в первый столбец, т.к. там мы раньше всех получили 1. Следующей итерацией переходим в первую строку в столбец 2(в 3 не переходим, т.к. не выполняется условие, 2 единицы), и там тоже получаем единицу, получаем:

```
1, 1, 1
1, none, none
none,none,none
```

Теперь переходим ко второй строчке в столбец 3, т.к. там в предыдущей ячейке получили раьше всех единицу. Если получаем там едицицу, то идём к третей строке столбец один. И каждая следующая итеррация прыгает между этими строками. Как только заполнится вторая строка, цикл работает между оставшимися ячейками третьей строки.

Это упрощенная модель, по факту матрица будет больше, и данные будут отбрасываться назад (если после единицы мы получаем 0, то ячейка с единицей этого столбца получает тоже ноль)